# Get body of GET request (NodeJS + axios)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

Here's my request:

```
        axios.get(BASE_URI + '/birds/random', {Stuff: "STUFF"})
        .then(randBird=>{
            const birdData = randBird.data
            const bird = {
                age: birdData.age,
                bio: birdData.profile.bio,
                displayname: birdData.profile.displayname,
                species: birdData.profile.species,
                _id: birdData._id
            }
            this.setState({currentBird:bird})
        })
```

Here's what happens on my router (on '/birds'):

```
birdRouter.route('/random').get((req, res)=>{
    console.log('req.body = ', req.body)
    User.count().exec((err, num)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
            return res.send({error: err})
        }
        const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * num)
        User.findOne().skip(random).exec((err, bird)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
                return res.send({error: err})
            }
            console.log(bird)
            res.send(bird)
        })

    })
```

Really, the only lines that are worth paying attention to in both snippets are the first and first two (for the first and second snippet, respectively).

The request goes through, but my console.log shows this:

```
req.body = {}
```

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Why didn't you use `req.query` while using GET requests ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some browsers and libraries don't support HTTP get method with a body. You can switch to POST/PUT and see if it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in GET method we are not passing body data. instead of body data you can pass in query string. and also if you are using express server than you need to install a package [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) to get data in body. please take a reference of issue posted in [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/787)